# THREE.js: Textures become grayish with renderer.OutputEncoding = sRGBEncoding

Tags: javascript, three.js, gamma, srgb

I'm playing a bit with the [Three.js cloth example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_animation_cloth.html) but instead of the alphaMap, I kept the cloth-plane fully opaque and changed its **color** map.
The result is quite disappointing as the texture now renders very grayish due to the OutputEncoding of the renderer (sRGB Encoding).
If I change the output encoding back to LinearEncoding, the grass texture appears to be too dark.

Below is the result:
[image]

And the original textures look like this:

[image]

Is there any way to remain with the sRGBEncoding but have my cloth texture render with much more contrast?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to remain with the sRGBEncoding but have my cloth texture render with much more contrast?

Yes. Just set the [encoding](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=text#api/en/textures/Texture.encoding) property of your texture to `THREE.sRGBEncoding`.

The default encoding value of textures is `THREE.LinearEncoding`. So if you don't modify it but a configure a sRGB workflow on renderer level, color textures will indeed look incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The examples above were taken with both ground and pictures set to sRGBEncoding. In the two pictures it doesn't seem to make any difference, as well as playing with gammaFactor.